# How can I access yaml maps using Typescript?

Tags: typescript, yaml

I'm parsing a yaml file using [yaml package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml), version 2.0.1. I know that this document should be a map, and I want to access it's property named "key". I tried doing it two different ways: both using primitive values and creating nodes myself, [as described in documentation](https://eemeli.org/yaml/#collections), but both result in errors:

```
declare const doc: yaml.Document.Parsed;

if (yaml.isMap(doc.contents)) {

  // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ParsedNode'
  doc.contents.get("key")

  // Argument of type 'Node' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ParsedNode'.
  doc.contents.get(doc.createNode("key"))
}
```

How am I supposed to access this map?

Comment: The docs you link use `yaml.Document`, you are using `yaml.Document.Parsed`. This is mentioned in the docs but never defined. It looks like you're trying to use internal types and should use the defined public types instead.

Comment: Library author confirmed that it is a known problem, I've opened a PR to update typings: https://github.com/eemeli/yaml/pull/383

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I've fixed this](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml/pull/383), so since [2.1.0 release of the package](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml/releases/tag/v2.1.0), the code in the question is now valid and doesn't give any type errors.